# PushSharp doesn't send notifications

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I have got a simple code:

```
PushBroker pushBroker = new PushBroker();
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + AppSettings.CertificatePath);
var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(path);        
pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(
           new ApplePushChannelSettings(AppSettings.IsProductionPushNotificationServer,
                                        appleCert,
                                        AppSettings.CertificatePassword));

var notification = new AppleNotification().ForDeviceToken(deviceToken.TrimStart('<').TrimEnd('>'))
                                          .WithBadge(unviewedInvitationCount);

pushBroker.QueueNotification(notification);
```

I try to use development and production sertificates with Sandbox and Production server respectively. But nothing is happened. Client side is able to get the push notifications.
What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:**

I subscribed on the events.

OnNotificationFailed says me about this error:

```
{APNS NotificationFailureException -> 5 : Invalid token size -> {"aps":{"badge":1}}}
```

And if I wrap my device token into <...> I receive another error:

```
{APNS NotificationFailureException -> 8 : Invalid token -> {"aps":{"badge":1}}}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your device token shouldn't have any spaces and '<' or '>' characters. It should contain 64 hexadecimal characters. If it doesn't, that explains the first error (invalid token size).

i.e, 
not `<3948de8f 3948de8f ...>` nor `3948de8f 3948de8f ...`

Only `3948de8f3948de8f...`

The second error (invalid token) probably means that you used a sandbox device token to push to the production APNS server or vice versa. Sandbox tokens shuold only be used in the sandbox env.

Comment: It worked for me. The "spaces" was the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me. Sanbox device token was the issue for me

Comment: YOU sir... just ended a very long day for me! Thank you SO much.